# “Victorians would have been great on social media. They’d have had their own emojis. Open brackets/close brackets means ‘I’ve got Rickets”

Tags: jokes

Can you explain what this joke means please?

“Victorians would have been great on social media. They’d have had their own emojis. Open brackets/close brackets means ‘I’ve got Rickets”

Hal Cruttenden: Straight Outta Cruttenden
(Pleasance Two)

Comment: Have you looked up "Rickets"?

Comment: @Stephie Yes I have :(

Answer (score 8):

[Rickets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickets) is an illness caused by vitamin D deficiency. One very obvious symptom are bow legs (long bones curved outwards). In this joke, the brackets represent the bowed legs of infant patients: **()**

During victorian time rickets was far more frequent than today, due to malnutrition in early childhood, child labour and lack of supplements - cod liver oil being the classic treatment.

Comment: I got it , it is so funny :))))